# Retweet schema in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What is the best way to model retweet schema in `MongoDB`? It is important that I have `createdAt` times of both original message and the time when retweet occurred because of pagination, I use `createdAt` as cursor for `GraphQL` query.

I also need a flag weather the message itself is retweet or original, and id references to original message and original user and reposter user.

I came up with 2 solutions, first one is that I keep ids of reposters and `createdAt` in array in Message model. The downside is that I have to generate timeline every time and for `subscription` its not clear what message to push to client.

The second is that I treat retweet as message on its own, I have `createdAt` and `reposterId` in place but I have a lot of replication, if I were to add like to message i have to push in array of every single retweet.

I could use help with this what is the most efficient way to do it in `MongoDB`?

**First way:**

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    text: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
      required: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true,
    },
    likesIds: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    reposts: [
      {
        reposterId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
        },
        createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

const Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
```

**Second way:**

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    text: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
      required: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true,
    },
    likesIds: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    isReposted: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    repost: {
      reposterId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
      },
      originalMessageId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Message',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

const Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);

export default Message;
```

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 is the better choice here. I'm operating with the assumption that this is a Twitter re-tweet or Facebook share like functionality. You refer to this functionality as both retweet and repost so I'll stick to "repost" here.

Option 1 creates an efficiency problem where, to find reposts for a user, the db needs to iterate over all of the `repost` arrays of all the `messageSchema` collections to ensure it found all of the `reposterIds`. Storing ids in mongo arrays in collection X referencing collection Y is great if you want to traverse from X to Y. It's not as nice if you want to traverse from Y to X.

With option 2, you can specify a more classic one-to-many relationship between messages and reposts that will be simpler and more efficient to query. Reposts and non-repost messages alike will ultimately be placed into `messageSchema` in the order the user made them, making organization easier. Option 2 also makes it easy to allow reposting users to add text of their own to the repost, where it can be displayed alongside the repost in the view this feeds into. This is popular on facebook where people add context to the things they share.

My one question is, why are three fields being used to track reposts in Option 2?

`isReposted`, `repost`.`reposterId` and `repost`.`originalMessageId` provide redundant data. All that you should need is an `originalMessageId` field that, if not null, contains a messageSchema key and, if null, signifies that the message is not itself a repost. If you really need it, the userId of the original message's creator can be found in that message when you query for it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I found out it's impossible to make realtime timeline with retweets with just cache updates without refetching because complexity goes exponentially.